# Custom Layout with click-able buttons

Tags: android

How can I make a Layout like this:

[image]

I have tried using https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout, but unable to make the Gravity as Centre in the XML.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_VKZCqEnHblNDdiY2UxODgtYWNhNS00MmU4LWE4NDMtZjQ1OWI5MDMxZTVh/edit?num=50&sort=name&layout=list&pli=1#

Answer (score 1):

well You can use a list view with item view having buttons generated dynamically according to the number of buttons you want in a single row

Comment: and apply button style with appropriate corner radius and background color to make the button curved like in the picture you've provided.

Comment: agree with @SubramanyaSheshadri  . There is another  way to create this layout in scroll view and the buttons having this curved border  style  but keep this  android:largeHeap="true"
 to enlarge heap size other wise it may crash in cell phones with low cache memory .